# Como introduzco el texto en la posicion 1 del combobox sin que descuadre el arraylist

Tags: java-swing

Tengo un combobox que tiene que tener los nombres de los doctores y ademas poder meter Todas las citas.El problmea es que el combobox se carga a partir de un arraylsit de objetos Doctores y al combobox solo se le pasa el nombre del doctor. Luego segun seleccione pues se crea un informe
Necesito que me aparezca `la posicion vacia al cargar el interfaz, luego el texto todas las citas y luego ya cada uno de los doctores.
Os dejo como cargo los doctores el metodo para el informe para que veais como voy sacar al informacion. y la clase doctor

```
ArrayList<Doctor> listaDoctoresC;

    /**
     * Creates new form InformeCitas
     */
    public InformeCitas(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, ArrayList<Doctor> listaDoctores) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        inicializarcomponentes();
        listaDoctoresC = listaDoctores;
        cargaListaMedicos();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
     public void inicializarcomponentes() {
         cmdDoctores.setSelectedIndex(-1);
         areaInforme.setText("");

     }
    public void cargaListaMedicos() {
        int i;
        String puestoCombo;
        for (i = 0; i < listaDoctoresC.size(); i++) {

            puestoCombo = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNombreDoctor();
            cmdDoctores.addItem(puestoCombo);
        }
    }

    public void generarinforme() {
        int i;
        String nombre;
        int consulta;
        String doctor = "";
        String especialidad = "";
        int numConsulta = 0;
        int numCitas = 0;
        String paciente = "";
        Date fecha = null;
        String fechaS = "";
        if (cmdDoctores.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < listaDoctoresC.size(); i++) {
                numCitas = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getListaCitas().size();
                numConsulta = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNumConsulta();
                                doctor = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNombreDoctor();
                Doctor d = (Doctor) listaDoctoresC.get(i);
                for (i = 0; i < d.getListaCitas().size(); i++) {
                    fecha = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getHora();
                    paciente = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getPac().getNombrepac();
                }
                            }
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < listaDoctoresC.size(); i++) {
                if (listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNombreDoctor().compareToIgnoreCase(cmdDoctores.getSelectedItem().toString()) == 0) {
                    especialidad = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getEspecialidad();
                    numConsulta = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNumConsulta();
                    numCitas = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getListaCitas().size();
                    doctor = cmdDoctores.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Doctor d = listaDoctoresC.get(i);
                    for (i = 0; i < d.getListaCitas().size(); i++) {
                        fecha = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getHora();
                        paciente = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getPac().getNombrepac();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        String mensaje = "";
                mensaje += "Doctor: " + doctor + "\n";
                mensaje += "Especialidad: " + especialidad + "\n";
                mensaje += "numero Consulta: " + numConsulta + "\n";
                if (numCitas == 0) {
                    mensaje += "--- Sin citas asignadas ---";
                } else {
                    mensaje += numCitas + "\t" + paciente + "\t" + fecha + "\n\n";
                }
                areaInforme.setText(mensaje);

    }
```

Esta es la clase doctor no ponog los getter y setter por ahorrar codigo y espacio en la pregunta

```
public class Doctor {

    private int codigo;
    private String nombreDoctor;
    private String especialidad;
    private int numConsulta;
    private List<Cita> listaCitas;

    public Doctor(int codigo, String especialidad, String nombreDoctor, int numConsulta, List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
        this.numConsulta = numConsulta;
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;
    }

    public Doctor(List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        this.listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: Creo que te falta mucho código del form. Podrías colgar el form completo? Gracias.

Comment: que codigo form? es todo lo que tengo de la clase informeCitas bueno aparte del codigo de los botones y eso